# Asynchronous Angular-bootsrap-UI typeahead: select directive issue

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

My application is using the `Angular-Bootstrap-UI-Typeahead` feature for auto complete.

As the user types, i'd like to be able to call an API & return similar strings.

I've followed the guidance [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), and everything works fine with the out of box Google API.

I've also successfully swapped in my own API: I am able to call the API, get the data, and log it in the correct format in my browser console.

However, I constantly get "no results found" from the text box. **I suspect this may be a problem with the select directive**, but i am stumped.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this!

Here is some code:

UI (content.html)

```
<h4>biz results</h4>
<pre>Model: {{user.orgName | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" 
ng-model="user.orgName" 
placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" 
uib-typeahead="obj for obj in getLocation($viewValue)" 
typeahead-loading="loadingBiz" 
typeahead-no-results="noBiz" class="form-control"
typeahead-wait-ms="700">
<i ng-show="loadingBiz" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noBiz">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
</div>
```

Angular (script.js)

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
var bizRequest = $http.post('/sample', {
  // var bizRequest = $http.post('/biz', {
      orgName: val,
      limit: 5
    }
  ).success(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    //console.log('Biz response: ' + JSON.stringify(response))
    //console.log(response.data.fields.map(item))
    var bizArray = response.data.fields.map(function(item){
      return item.fields.orgName;
    });
    console.log(bizArray);
    return bizArray;
  });
  console.log("Biz Request /////// " + JSON.stringify(bizRequest))
  return bizRequest
};
```

Node API (app.js)

```
app.post('/sample', function(req, res){

var resp = {
"success": true,
"data": {
    "fields": [{
        "fields": {
            "scid": "1111",
            "orgName": "1111",
            "countryCode": "1",
            "countryName": "1",
            "cityName": "1",
            "addressLine": "1111"
        },
        "matchedRule": {
            "duplicateLevel": "POTENTIAL_MATCH",
            "id": "18",
            "rank": "1"
        }
    }, {
        "fields": {
            "scid": "2222",
            "orgName": "2222",
            "countryCode": "22",
            "countryName": "22",
            "cityName": "22",
            "addressLine": "2 22"
        },
        "matchedRule": {
            "duplicateLevel": "POTENTIAL_MATCH",
            "id": "18",
            "rank": "1"
        }
    }]
},
"errors": [],
"warnings": [],
"infoMessages": []
}

res.send(JSON.stringify(resp))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `promise` from `getLocation` method while dealing asynchronous typeahead. So don't use `.success` there which would break promise chain. Instead use `.then` which would help you to chain promise and you can return data from `.then` to pass it to `typeahead`

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
  var bizRequest = $http.post('/sample', {
  // var bizRequest = $http.post('/biz', {
      orgName: val,
      limit: 5
    }
  ).then(function(data){
    response = data.data; //<-- take data in response.
    console.log(response.data)
    //console.log('Biz response: ' + JSON.stringify(response))
    //console.log(response.data.fields.map(item))
    var bizArray = response.data.fields.map(function(item){
      return item.fields.orgName;
    });
    console.log(bizArray);
    return bizArray;
  });
  console.log("Biz Request /////// " + JSON.stringify(bizRequest))
  return bizRequest
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I switch ".success" to ".then", I get a different error:      angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at script.js:67
    at processQueue (angular.js:16383)
    at angular.js:16399
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17495)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at done (angular.js:11831)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)

Comment: just change data.data to response.data and everything works great. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @JefferyMeurot Happy to know that it helped, Thanks ;)